# Is their any Stotra, Stava, Stuti, et cetera for Mohini?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, stotra, hymn

Vishnu manifested into Mohini and gave Devas the ambrosial nectar, and rendered Daityas bereft of Amrita. Then She even cut Rahu Ketu apart.

There have always been innumerable Stutis of each Avatara of Vishnu. In some stotras of Vishnu, Mohini is sometimes collectively worshipped with other Avataras usually in Sahasra Naama Stotras of Hari.

Are there any Stora, Stuti, Stava, et cetera for Mohini?